# H2 database content is not persisting on insert and update

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, h2, slick

I am using h2 database to test my postgres slick functionality.

I created a below h2DbComponent:

```
    trait H2DBComponent extends DbComponent {

      val driver = slick.jdbc.H2Profile
      import driver.api._
      val h2Url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;INIT=runscript from './test/resources/schema.sql'\\;runscript from './test/resources/schemadata.sql'"

      val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

      val db: Database = {
        logger.info("Creating test connection ..................................")
        Database.forURL(url = h2Url, driver = "org.h2.Driver")
      }
    }
```

In the above snippet i am creating my tables using schema.sql and inserting a single row(record) with schemadata.sql.

Then i am trying to insert a record into the table as below using my test case:

```
    class RequestRepoTest extends FunSuite with RequestRepo with H2DBComponent {

      test("Add new Request") {
        val response = insertRequest(Request("XYZ","tk", "DM", "RUNNING", "0.1", "l1", "file1",
          Timestamp.valueOf("2016-06-22 19:10:25"), Some(Timestamp.valueOf("2016-06-22 19:10:25")), Some("scienceType")))
        val actualResult=Await.result(response,10 seconds)
        assert(actualResult===1)

        val response2 = getAllRequest()
        assert(Await.result(response2, 5 seconds).size === 2)
      }
    }
```

The above assert of insert works fine stating that the record is inserted. But the getAllRequest() assert fails as the output still contains the single row(as inserted by schemadata.sql) => which means the insertRequest change is not persisted. However the below statements states that the record is inserted as the insert returned 1 stating one record inserted.

```
    val response = insertRequest(Request("CMP_XYZ","tesco_uk", "DM", "RUNNING", "0.1", "l1", "file1",
        Timestamp.valueOf("2016-06-22 19:10:25"), Some(Timestamp.valueOf("2016-06-22 19:10:25")), 
        Some("scienceType")))
    val actualResult=Await.result(response,10 seconds)
```

Below is my definition of insertRequest:

```
    def insertRequest(request: Request):Future[Int]= {
        db.run { requestTableQuery += request }
    }
```

I am unable to figure out how can i see the inserted record. Is there any property/config which i need to add?

Comment: You could have a look at [Acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/) to unit test JDBC based code (I'm a contributor of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the getAllRequest() assert fails as the output still contains the single row(as inserted by schemadata.sql) => which means the insertRequest change is not persisted

I would double-check that the `assert(Await.result(response2, 5 seconds).size === 2)` line is failing because of a size difference. Could it be failing for some other general failure?

For example, as `INIT` is run on each connection it could be that you are re-creating the database for each connection. Unless you're careful with the SQL, that could produce an error such as "table already exists". Adding `TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;` to your H2 URL can be helpful in tracking what H2 is doing.

A couple of suggestions.

First, you could ensure your SQL only runs as needed. For example, your `schema.sql` could add checks to avoid trying to create the table twice:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table( my_column VARCHAR NULL );
```

And likewise for your `schemadata.sql`:

```
MERGE INTO my_table KEY(my_column) VALUES ('a') ;
```

Alternatively, you could establish schema and test data around your tests (e.g., possibly in Scala code, using Slick). Your test framework probably has a way to ensure something is run before and after a test or test suit.

Comment: Adding property "TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;" helped. While executing every database request, it is creating connection and then disconnecting. Any suggestion if i want to use the same db connection for suppose 4 tests in the same file "RequestRepoTest".

Comment: I'm not sure how to get Slick to definitely use just a single connection in that way without changing your actions (if you really want to try that, look at creating a custom executor when you create the `db`). IInstead of that, I'd suggest setting up a scenario to test around a set of tests. Here's an example: https://github.com/d6y/example-slick-h2-test